# Chronological order of the three Tiassa sections?

Tags: steven-brust, vlad-taltos, chronological-order

From [Wikipedia's page on Steven Brust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Brust), the chronological order of the books is as follows:

1. Taltos (1988)
2. Dragon (1998)
3. Yendi (1984)
4. Tiassa, section 1 (2011)
5. Jhereg (1983)
6. Teckla (1987)
7. Phoenix (1990)
8. Jhegaala (2008)
9. Athyra (1993)
10. Orca (1996)
11. Issola (2001)
12. Dzur (2006)
13. Tiassa, section 2 (2011)
14. Iorich (2010)
15. Tiassa, section 3 (2011)

Are there proofs and counter-proofs for the timing of the book, especially sections two and three? Has Steven Brust said anything about this?

Comment: I’m still trying to figure out when the middle interlude happened, the one with Aliera and Kieron.

Answer (score 5):

Steven Brust himself hasn't said anything on the subject, other than to confirm that he did write Dragon to make it impossible to read the series in chronological order, and that Tiassa goes back and forward in time.[(1)](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2010/01/a-conversation-with-steven-brust-about-writing-the-dragaera-books)

However, an [unofficial timeline](http://www.panix.com/~alexx/dragtime.html) has been compiled by Alexx Kay with much research and help that has had a lot of effort and research put into it, and contains reference material for the reasons for the conclusions drawn.  Without input from the man himself, I think this is as close as anyone can hope to come.  It was last updated (as of this writing) on August 6, 2011, so it's pretty up-to-date and actively maintained.

Comment: I had given up hopes of getting any answer to this. Thanks  very much.

Comment: I think you misread Brust’s wording about *Tiassa* being both forward and backward in time. Its various chapters and interludes take place at different parts of Vlad’s life, but there seem to be no actual time travel; indeed, Devera specifically rules it out. *Tiassa* part 1 is right after *Yendi*; part 2 is after *Issola*; part 3 is after *Iorich*. ‘Conception’ is difficult to place temporally, by design. The Epilogue is a retelling of the last chapter by Vlad not Paarfi. ɴᴏᴛᴇ: This is nearly the *end of the Vlad cycle,* which bookends him between ages 17 and 34, for mystical reasons.

Comment: @tchrist - I never said anything about time travel.  It's just that Dragon doesn't cover any one time period, but multiple time periods.  Then, his own words: *For those who want to know if it is going to move backward: Yes. For those who want to know if it is going to move forward: Yes.*  Pretty clear in his own words IMO.